# Legalization of parimutuel betting format

Tags: gambling

What's the legality around using a [parimutuel betting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parimutuel_betting) format for events in general (i.e., outside of horse or greyhound racing)?

I haven't seen any references where a parimutuel betting system is used for political or economic events. It's not clear whether this is due to

1. Technology constraints,
2. Legality or
3. Public interest.

Comment: jurisdiction tag is needed

Comment: This type of betting is common across all types of sports betting, not just horses and dogs.

Comment: in this case, jurisdiction is very needed. In many countries there's a blanket ban on all gambling.

Comment: This is mis-tagged. [tag:jurisdiction] is "*For questions concerning whether a body has the power to make a legal decision on a particular matter.*" The comment was asking for the relevant country, province, state etc

Comment: "Parimutuel betting or pool betting is a betting system in which all bets of a particular type are placed together in a pool; taxes and the "house-take" or "vigorish" are deducted, and payoff odds are calculated by sharing the pool among all winning bets."

Answer (score 0):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Sports betting is authorized by specific state and federal statutes that apply only to within their scope. Gambling is generally illegal in most jurisdictions otherwise.

> I haven't seen any references where a parimutuel betting system is
> used for political or economic events.

The main way that something similar to this is organized is as a "predictions market."

The status of "prediction markets" is legally indeterminate. There are arguments that it constitutes gambling, although the counterargument is that it is a matter of skill. There are also questions about whether this activity is subject to regulation as a securities market or a commodity futures market.

Generally, the prevailing view is that this is a commodity future rather than a security or a gambling arrangement for regulatory purposes, largely on the theory that it is a "[derivative contract](https://www.cfainstitute.org/en/advocacy/issues/derivatives)." in part, the distinction between this and gambling, is the potential for economically legitimate transactions in predictions markets to hedge against risks - much like insurance contracts which also add economic stakes to predictions, but not in the context of an insurance policy.

A somewhat dated 2009 law review articles examining the question can be found [here](https://scholarship.law.vanderbilt.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=1012&context=faculty-publications) and [here](http://www.tomwbell.com/writings/PrivatePMs&theLaw.pdf). Another in 2011 can be found [here](https://www.pennstatelawreview.org/116/2/116%20Penn%20St.%20L.%20Rev.%20403.pdf).

A [2018 blog post](https://politicalpredictionmarkets.com/is-predictit-legal/) references a no action letter from the Commodity Futures Trading Commission (CFTC) effectively blessing one particular firm's prediction market. Bloomberg reports [as of May 26, 2022](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2022-05-26/kalshi-s-stock-market-of-the-world-let-s-you-bet-on-anything?leadSource=uverify%20wall) (in a paywalled article) that at least one such predictions market was operating legally with CFTC approval.